# Will update Ubuntu to a newer release replace a newer kernel than the supported kernel of that release?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 20.04

Last week I installed Linux 5.9 on my Ubuntu 20.04.1, and 2-3 days ago I upgraded to Linux 5.9.1.
I read that Groovy Gorilla comes with Linux 5.8, what will happen with the newer version of the kernel? Will be substituted? Both kernels will be installed? The older version won't be installed?

Comment: It may depend on how you installed the kernel, you may have issues with the upgrade (from 20.04.1 to 20.04.2 and 5.8 kernel) or you may have both. It'll depend I bet on how you installed the non-Ubuntu or *testing* kernel.

Comment: @guiverc I used this script for updating the kernel https://github.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh

Comment: That is a manual (non-Canonical/non-Ubuntu) script, so you've taken on the responsibility of upgrades for kernels now (having switched to an unsupported kernel as the link clearly states).  Use `ubuntu-security-status` to validate your own system for yourself.

Comment: When I get home I do it.

Comment: @guiverc command not found

Comment: try `ubuntu-support-status`  (the command got renamed from that to `ubuntu-security-status` sometime, but sorry i forget when (ie. at which release it switched)...

Comment: @guiverc Sorry for the delay. I upgraded to groovy yesterday and all works well. In the update, Ubuntu installed the kernel 5.8, but didn't remove the 5.9. When rebooting, booted the newer kernel. I will keep the 5.8 for booting it from the grub menu in case there is any problem.

Comment: It won't remove the 5.9 as that kernel is your responsibility (not a Ubuntu supported kernel); you've installed it, all security updates/patches for it are your responsibility etc. Don't forget that!  *My hirsute Ubuntu system is still using 5.8 which is expected so early into the cycle, my Debian system has upgraded currently to 5.9 I noted yesterday; by sticking with supported kernels I avoid the manual security & maintenance hassle*

Answer (score 0):

Updating Ubuntu won't delete a newer kernel. Will install the supported kernel of the release, but will use the newer.

Comment: May not always be valid.  If you installed a supported kernel (eg. from -proposed) it could end up being deleted... In your case it was partially how you did it outside of the Ubuntu packaging system, thus the package system (database) doesn't know of it's existence, it may have been deleted if it clashed with a package upgrade, or worse may have stopped an upgrade from occurring because of the file being present which may impact other users (as it was not recorded in the package database).  Your answer doesn't include the caveats that match the circumstance.